# Media Query width:100% causing overflow

Tags: css, html, overflow, media

I am designing my first responsive website. Things were great until now when I set container div to be 100%. The idea was to have to container div to be 100% with max width 768px. If the browser window is less than 768px, the container show take up 100% screen size WITHOUT overflow.

It looks like setting .container {width: 100%} is making the container a fixed 678px even when screen size is smaller, thus causing overflow.

Can someone help?

Example:

```
/* --- Main style - not media --- */

html, body {
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 829px;
}
.all-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
}
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 6.0em;
width: 70%;
left: 0;
max-width: 1140px;
min-width: 500px;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.content-box {
position: relative;
width: 80%;
margin: 2.0em auto 3.0em;
padding: 1.0em;
}


/* -------Media -----------*/

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.main {
    max-width: 100%
    min-width: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.content-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 4.0em;
}
}

    /*-- html ----*/
<div class= "main">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
        <p>stuff</p>                
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd remove every `width` rule and add `max-width: 768px;`, a block element is 100% unless told otherwise, setting `width: 100%` can come with weird side effects (on for ex. a iPad). This code alone isn't enough to completely help out though, the fixed 678px is a mystery without seeing more.

Comment: please provide html for container (and it's container if it has one) and any style for the parent and body

Comment: why do you have a second 0 on margin 0 auto; ? Also, please provide us a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Marcel Initial width for block elements is `auto`, which is not the same as `100%`, it's more like `calc(100% - margins)`

Comment: @Marcel, here's the relevant css and html. For the main css (not media) I cannot always do max 100% because of the way its laid out, but I did try max-width: 100% for the media and its still not working. It's overflowing. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: OK, I got this. I had a minimum width set in the non-media css which was overwriting the 100% screen width for media query. As soon as I took those off, it stopped overflowing, taking up the width of the screen size instead.